# ScrollView is getting struck while doing pagination for tableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have added dynamic height tableView inside the scrollView. I have implemented pagination for the tableview i.e when the user loads the page the the api will e called and when the user reached to end of the scrollView then I am calling another Api and then tableView Reload() method is getting called. The issue when the scroll reaches the end the until the tableview get reload the app is the scrollView is getting struck and unable to click any where on the app

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tbl.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollview.contentOffset.y >= (scrollview.contentSize.height - scrollview.frame.size.height)) 
    {
       
        
        //user has scrolled to the bottom
        spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: tbl.bounds.width, height: 40)
        //spinner.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
        self.tbl.tableFooterView = spinner
        self.tbl.tableFooterView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tbl.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false

        if dataLoading == false{
            spinner.startAnimating()
            loadMoreActivities()
        }

    }
}
func loadMoreActivities(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.PageNo += 1
        self.dataLoading = true
        ApiService.Call(endPoint: API , params: params, httpMethod: method,header: ApiService.GetHeader_Auth(),informSuccess: false,encoding: .httpBody,vcSender: self,shouldAnimate: true) { (Result : JSON) in
            
            if !ApiService.IsResponseOK(result: Result)
            {
                
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                return
            
            }
            self.tbl.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
            if let data = try? Result["Data"].rawData()
            {
                
                self.listOfActivities = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Activities.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tbl.ForceReload()
                    }
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
             }
           }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you put a TableView in a ScrollView? If not, move your table out from scroll view and this stuff will be easier!

Comment: @Alessandro - I had 2 view and 1 Tableview in a ScrollView. Its requirement for me to increase the height of theTtableview Dynamically so I have added tableView in the ScrollView.

Comment: Ok i don't know how your code is structured but, table view are able to increase it's size depending on contents so, you could use tableview outside of scrollview. Otherwise, you should calculate the height of your table view (number_of_cells*height_of_cell) and assign it to scroll view content size. By the way, if your cells have dynamic height this could be tedious.

Comment: @Alessandro- the tableView cells are having dynamic height

Comment: in this case, you have to calculate the height of any cell depending of their contents and then calculate the tableview height